# Match numbers and letters/numbers using regex java (by separated)

Tags: java, regex, match, matching

what it's the correct form to match when an String is number o letters/number, for example, I have this code

```
String regexNum = "\\d*";
String regexVar = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*";

if(valor.matches(regexNum))
{
   System.out.println("It's a number");
}
if(valor.matches(regexVar))
{
   System.out.println("It's a variable");
}
```

When I enter for example "SAL45", the output is "It's a variable", what's fine, so, when a I enter "45", the output is "It's a variable" again but I need to output be "It's a number", how can I fix that mistake?

Comment: make var start with a letter maybe? `"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"`

Comment: It works, thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your regex is not correct.**

**Here is the Condition for Number :**

1. Length Must greater than zero
2. All there character should be digits

**And Here is the Condition for a Variable :**

1. Must Start with `_` or Alphabet [a-zA-Z] or `$`
2. Other Character Should be `_`, Number[0-9], Alphabet[a-zA-Z], `$`

```
    String regexNum = "\\d+";
    String regexVar = "[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*";

    if (valor.matches(regexNum)) {
        System.out.println("It's a number");
    }
    if (valor.matches(regexVar)) {
        System.out.println("It's a variable");
    }
```

Comment: Should probably add in dollar sign as well!

Comment: Thanks @flkes $ sign added

Answer (score 2):

With "45", both messages are printed. You just need to make use of else to show only one message. Here's the corrected code:-

```
String regexNum = "\\d*";
String regexVar = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*";

if(valor.matches(regexNum))
{
   System.out.println("It's a number");
}
else if(valor.matches(regexVar))
{
   System.out.println("It's a variable");
}
```